# Get all texts between html tags in string

Tags: php

i have a string like that:

```
test test test <span> hello </span> test test test <span> hello2 </span>
```

and i try to get the text between the span tags like:

```
array [

0 => 'hello',
1 => 'hello2
];
```

i tried:

```
$regex = '#<\s*?span\b[^>]*>(.*?)</span\b[^>]*>#s';
$matches = [];
$item->text = preg_match($regex,  $item->text, $matches);
```

but there i only get the first match: 'hello'

Comment: [You should use a html parser](https://tio.run/##fY0xC8IwEIVn8ytuENoORXBtrSAVHKwuxf1oz2ZIc8GkiIi/PTat4uZyvPf4js9I432@NdIIsWy5hw1oukN5rkpuhp60y6Y9LRRje6irYxw5sg5@J7cGdQGSlGLIV3P7w6y/UJRkozREO2pnS0duryh47e5RY3fCnuIoMIG@8o2wkRB/vtDClBJ4igU1kueaFppbuqAaKBMv798).

Comment: @0stone0, well that's even *more* correct

Comment: preg_match_all('/<span>([^`]*?)<\/span>/i', $text, $temp);

Answer (score 0):

What you need is:

```
$matches = [];
preg_match_all('/#<\s*?span\b[^>]*>(.*?)</span\b[^>]*>#s/', $input, $matches);
```